# How do I get the Cell Address from a Variable VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I created a variable **oldPassword** which is populated using a VLookup.

I am trying to get now the cell address from that result but nothing seem to work.

```vb
Dim oldPassword As String 

oldPassword = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1.Value, Worksheets("Employees").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
```

Comment: Use find instead. Vlookup only returns the value. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

Comment: you're missing `.Address` at the end of your statement to get the Address property of the found element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should break the task into steps

1. Get a reference to the cell containing the search value
2. Use that reference to get the required value and address

```vb
Sub Demo
    Din rSearch As Range
    Dim rUser as Range
    Dim rPassword As Range
    Dim idx As Variant 

    Set rSearch = Worksheets("Employees").Range("A:B")
    idx = Application.Match(Me.ComboBox1.Value, rSearch.Columns(1), 0)
    If Not IsError(idx) Then
        Set rUser = rSearch.Cells(idx, 1)
        Set rPassword = rUser.Cells(1, 2)
        ' get the result
        oldPassword = rPassword.Value2
        ' get the address
        Debug.Print rPassword.Address
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using [.Find](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) as @Andreas suggested but then that is my personal preference.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Employees")
    
    Dim aCell As Range
    Set aCell = ws.Columns(1).Find(What:=ComboBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
             
    Dim oldPassword As String
    
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        With aCell.Offset(, 1)
            '~~> Do what you want with that cell
            oldPassword = .Value2
            
            MsgBox .Address
        End With
    Else '<~~ Optional
        MsgBox ComboBox1.Value & " not found!" 
    End If
End Sub
```